# How to click a link that has javascript:__doPostBack in href?

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize

I am writing a screen scraper script in python with module 'mechanize' and I would like to use the mechanize.click_link() method on a link that has javascript:__doPostBack in href. 
I believe the page I am trying to parse is using AJAX.

Note: mech is the mechanize.Browser()

```
>>> next_link.__class__.__name__
'Link'
>>> next_link
Link(base_url='http://www.citius.mj.pt/Portal/consultas/ConsultasDistribuicao.aspx', url="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Pager1$lnkNext','')", text='2', tag='a', attrs=[('id', 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Pager1_lnkNext'), ('title', 'P\xc3\xa1gina seguinte: 2'), ('href', "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Pager1$lnkNext','')")])
>>> req = mech.click_link(next_link)
>>> req
<urllib2.Request instance at 0x025BEE40>
>>> req.has_data()
False
```

I would like to retrieve the page source after clicking the link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't use mechanize, but I do a lot of web scraping myself with python.

When I run into a javascript function like __doPostBack, I do the following:
I access the web site in Firefox, and use the [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) extension to see the parameters of the POST request the browser sent to the web server when clicking the relevant link.
I then build the same request in python using urllib.parse.urlencode to build the query strings and POST data I need.
Sometimes the website uses cookies as well, so I just use python's http.cookiejar.

I have used this technique successfully several times.

Comment: what should I do when I get the response, how do I decode it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `mechanize` supports Javascript; to scrape pages which intrinsically rely on Javascript execution for their functionality, you may need to use a different tool, such as [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> next_link.__class__.__name__
'Link'
>>> next_link
Link(base_url='http://www.citius.mj.pt/Portal/consultas/ConsultasDistribuicao.aspx', url="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Pager1$lnkNext','')", text='2', tag='a', attrs=[('id', 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Pager1_lnkNext'), ('title', 'P\xc3\xa1gina seguinte: 2'), ('href', "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Pager1$lnkNext','')")])
>>> req = mech.click_link(next_link)
>>> req
<urllib2.Request instance at 0x025BEE40>
>>> req.has_data()
False
```