# How can I convert a link that has javascript:do_postback to url?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-scraping

I'm trying to feed url into crawl websites which request urls for bulk extraction or crawling but the webpage I am interested is in apsx format and all the pages are coded as

```
href="javascript:__doPostBack('AspNetPager1','3')
href="javascript:__doPostBack('AspNetPager1','4')
href="javascript:__doPostBack('AspNetPager1','5')
```

would there be a way to get the url for the page links so that I can feed it into the bulk extraction modals?

A similar post I found on stackoverflow is

[How to convert a link that has javascript:__doPostBack in href to normal url which wget/curl/lynx can understand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210403/how-to-convert-a-link-that-has-javascript-dopostback-in-href-to-normal-url-whi)

But I am not following the answer, I've installed firebug but I'm not sure what extracting url from the "network traffic" actually entails. I'm not familiar with python or computer language, I'm only trying to extract text from websites through user friendly websites such as import.io.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking about how to interpret the answer of another Stack Overflow question that specifically indicates the Original Question, as written, does not have a solution.

Comment: It seems to me like this is a solvable problem.  It seems like a big ask, though not having shown any effort. I'd vote to reopen.