# Scraping of website that present a choice after login before retrieve the searched page

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I try to scrape a website that has a strange behavior.
I point as URL the page I want to retrieve, as normal website present me login page, I submit the form elements and then I want to scrape the page but after I submit the form the website present me a page with a choice (two links) to choose my profile, after the click on a chosed profile I can access the page I want. In mechanize I can't click on a link to retrieve the page I want to read.
This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib3
import mechanize
import cookielib
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("the_url_I_want_scrape")
br.select_form(nr=2)
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
br.form['username'] = "my_user"
br.form["password"] = "my_pass"
br.form["button.submit"] = "entra"
br.submit()
html = br.response().read()
```

Now if i iterate in a links I have two objects:

```
for link in br.links():
    print link
```

That it's look like follow lines:

```
Link(base_url='https://www.sito.com/internal/login', url='/internal/sessionProperty?sessid=1111', text='Profile1', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/nternal/sessionProperty?sessid=1111')])
Link(base_url='https://www.sito.com/internal/login', url='/shres/internal/sessionProperty?sessid=3333', text='Profile2', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/internal/sessionProperty?sessid=3333')])
```

How can I simulate a click on it and the parse the result page?
I've tried to add abolute_url to the link and then use follow_link but it hangs and not respond anymore
The code I use is:

```
for link in br.links():
  link.absolute_url = mechanize.urljoin(link.base_url,link.url)
  br.follow_link(link)
```

Someone can help me?
Thank you
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar experience when I needed to scrape website with heavy Javascript use (like hidden menus) and had to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) to simulate browser behaviour instead of mechanize. You could try that.

You could also track the POST request as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418000/how-to-click-a-link-that-has-javascript-dopostback-in-href?rq=1) question and try to simulate it.